# How to have an intersection type with one type information erased?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-declaration

I am working on a project where a Java Game has a JavaScript scripting API.
In order to get autocompletion for the scripting inside of an editor, I want to write typings for the API.

The Java side of the game uses wrapper classes to convert multiple types into one and I am struggling to represent that in a `d.ts` file.

```
// d.ts
interface ItemStack {
    someItemStackFunction(): void;
}

interface ItemStackWrapper {
    of(item: itemID): ItemStack;
}

declare const Item: ItemStackWrapper;

declare type itemID = `${string}:${string}`;
declare type ItemStackOrID = ItemStack & itemID;

// ts
const item = Item.of('something:something'); // valid ItemStack

function testing(arg: ItemStackOrID): void {
    // arg has information about everything from string here
    // like charAt() but should only have someItemStackFunction()
    // from ItemStack
    console.log(arg);
}
```

For the `testing` function, `itemID` and `ItemStack` should be allowed. However, I only want to have the type information of `ItemStack`. With the current approach, I also get all the type information from `string` because `itemID` is a string and I am intersecting them.

Is it possible to map two different types to one so I only get auto-completion for everything inside `ItemStack`?
The conversion of `itemID` to `ItemStack` is handled internally inside the Java side of the game. I just want to represent that you can pass two types to the function but it should only show type information for one type.

A union type wouldn't be a valid solution either because this would erase all type information completely.

Comment: Why are you using an intersection if it's one **or** the other? An intersection means **and**.

Comment: Because a union erases all type information if you don't do any checks.

Comment: And an intersection mandates providing all values.. in this case a value which should satisfy that it be a string and an interface both.

Comment: What do you mean by "erasing" type information? Are you talking about what types are displayed in your IDE with IntelliSense? If so: a value of type `X` or `Y` should be a union `X | Y` and not an intersection `X & Y`; the fact that `X & Y` gives you some desirable IDE experience doesn't change the fact that it is not the right type. It's as if you dropped your keys in a dark alley, but I find you searching for them a block away. I tell you that you should probably try looking for them where you dropped them, and you say "but it's brighter under the streetlamp here". ‍♂️

Comment: I am well aware of how intersections and unions work and what their differences are. The problem with a union here is that TS will not know which type of them it is so I will have no IntelliSense at all until I do some proper checks to narrow down the actual type. So I chose the intersection to have at least some IntelliSense although that means I get suggestions from both types. But my goal is to accept a string and ItemStack but it should be treated as just ItemStack within the function. My question was if that's even possible.

Comment: Well, you absolutely should not write the wrong type just because you want "better" IntelliSense suggestions. Write a type which correctly describes what type it will actually be; in this case, that's a union type. Then if you accept either a string or an `ItemStack` then you need to write code which correctly handles either type of value. You cannot have a function which accepts strings but only handles `ItemStack`s correctly, unless you specifically want your function to be wrong.

Comment: Well, you *can* use overloads to upcast/downcast parameters in implementations compared to call signatures. But this really seems like an XY problem where Y is not the best way to achieve X; instead of pretending you have `ItemID & ItemStack` and then pretending that you have an `ItemStack`, you should have a function that retrieves an `ItemStack` for a given `ItemId` and then you can use it to *convert* `ItemID | ItemStack` into `ItemStack`, no pretending required. [This code](https://tsplay.dev/NrKP0m) shows both methods. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

As per the explanation, I think using a `Union Type` with [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) in the `testing` function parameter should be an obvious choice...

```ts
interface ItemStack {
  someItemStackFunction(): void;
}

interface ItemStackWrapper {
  of(item: itemID): ItemStack;
}

declare const Item: ItemStackWrapper;

declare type itemID = `${string}:${string}`;
declare type ItemStackOrID = ItemStack | itemID;

// ts
const item = Item.of('something:something'); // valid ItemStack

function testing(arg: Exclude<ItemStackOrID, itemID>): void {
  // arg now is strictly ItemStack
  console.log(arg.someItemStackFunction());
}
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Isn't this just to exclude some specific type from the union? That means the method would only accept `ItemStack` but I need it to accept both. But no matter what's passed, it should be treated as `ItemStack`.

Comment: If we take in a `Union`, it will have all unless we narrow it down. Can you have 2 or more functions?

Comment: There are [Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as well, if you are open to using them in conjunction with `testing` function...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you mentioned you want to write only type declarations... which means implementation should take care of the value, your declarations should be fine with a union then... as after all you want to accept either of the two types...

Comment: The use case is a bit complicated to explain here since it's about game development and scripting. My example code just shows an example of what the use case would be. I basically try to represent Java methods with TS typings. The Java part uses internal wrappers so it doesn't matter if you pass in a string or an ItemStack, it will always treat it as ItemStack.
Type Predicates look like they are only handy for return types but I need to have a parameter accepting two types while being one type explicitely.

Comment: Actually type predicates are handy for discriminating inside a Union Type, the return is a boolean, which helps us identify a particular union member from rest of the others.